# How to extract location name from lat and lon

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have extracted longitude and latitude using geolocation plugin in flutter. But now I need to create name of place from those longitude and latitude.

I tried using geocoder plugin, but

```
  final coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
          var addresses =  Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);

      var first = addresses.first;
```

above line is giving error saying getter first is not defined for class Future<>

```
      print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
```

How can I use those latitude and longitude and convert into address in flutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findAddressesFromCoordinates` returns a [`Future`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) in this case.

You can either make your function or method `async`:

```
void yourFunction() async {
  final coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
  var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);

  var first = addresses.first; 
  print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
}
```

In this case you need to use the `await` keyword in front of your method call, which will make the function only continue running **after** your object *with the addresses* has been retrieved.

The other option is using the `then` method on a `Future`, which would look like this:

```
void yourFunction() {
  final coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
  Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates).then((addresses) {
    var first = addresses.first; 
    print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
  });
}
```

In this case you are passing a callback to the `then` method, which will be executed with the result of `findAddressesFromCoordinates` in it once they are returned, but `yourFunction` itself will continue running.

Answer (score 2):

the **findAddressesFromCoordinates** method return a `Future<List<Address>>`

so you can do something like using **then** :

```
final coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
var addresses =  
Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates).then(
(data) => print(data);
);
```

or you can just use the async/await :

```
getAddressesFromCoordinates() async {
final coordinates = new Coordinates(1.10, 45.50);
addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
first = addresses.first;
print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");}
```

if you want to understand the basics of Asynchronous Programming in dart you should take a look at this [article](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures)

Answer (score 1):

try this google instead on local

```
final coordinates = new Coordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);  
geocoder.google('GOOGLE_API_KEY').findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of geocoding you can get Placemark using LatLan. But sometimes you will get a meaningless 'name' for that specific LatLng, in that case, you can do a little modification for getting a meaningful 'name' as shown below.

```
Future<String> getLocationFromLatLng(LatLng latLng) async {
  List<Placemark> place = await placemarkFromCoordinates(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);
  int len = place.length;
  String name = '';
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    String temp = place[i].name ?? '';
    if(name.length <= temp.length){
      name = temp;
    }
  }
  return name;
}
```